# Django no app_label in model

Tags: python, django

I have a django rest app called hotels, my structure directory is the following:

```
app/
├── config
│   ├── asgi.py
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── __pycache__
│   ├── settings.py
│   ├── urls.py
│   └── wsgi.py
├── hotels
│   ├── admin.py
│   ├── apps.py
│   ├── filters.py
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── migrations
│   ├── models.py
│   ├── __pycache__
│   ├── serializers.py
│   ├── tests
│   └── views.py
├── __init__.py
└── __pycache__
    └── __init__.cpython-38.pyc
```

In the [models.py](https://models.py) file I have defined a class called HotelChain as follows:

```
class HotelChain(TimestampedModel):
    PRICE_CHOICES = [
        (1, "$"),
        (2, "$$"),
        (3, "$$$"),
        (4, "$$$$"),
    ]

    title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=50)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=50, blank=True)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True)
    website = models.URLField(max_length=250, blank=True)
    sales_contact = models.CharField(max_length=250, blank=True)
    price_range = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(null=True, blank=True, choices=PRICE_CHOICES)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.title}"
```

​

But I am getting this error:

```
RuntimeError: Model class app.hotels.models.HotelChain doesn't declare an explicit app_label and isn't in an application in INSTALLED_APPS.
```

​

I tried adding

```
class Meta:
        app_label = 'hotels'
```

To the class definition but it doesn't fix the issue.

My app config is this one:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'hotels',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'rest_framework',
    'django_filters',
    'import_export',
)
```